# How to link a multiselect widget to a datatable using bokeh in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, datatable, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, multi-select

I'm attempting to connect a datatable with a multiselect widget in bokeh. I've searched around and gathered that I need to develop a function to update the data source for the data table, but I seem to have two problems.

1. I cannot seem to access the value of the multiselect object after I click it.
2. I cannot seem to push the change to the notebook after receiving the change.

Here's an example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import push_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models.widgets import MultiSelect, DataTable, TableColumn
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

output_notebook()

df=pd.DataFrame({'year':[2000,2001,2000,2001,2000,2001,2000,2001],
              'color':['red','blue','green','red','blue','green','red','blue'],
              'value':[ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

columns=[TableColumn(field=x, title=x) for x in df.columns]
source=ColumnDataSource(df)
data_table=DataTable(source=source,columns=columns)

years=[2000,2001,2000,2001,2000,2001,2000,2001]

## MultiSelect won't let me store an integer value, so I convert them to strings

multi=MultiSelect(title="Select a Year", value=['2000','2001'],options=[str(y) for y in set(years)])

def update(attr,old, new):
    yr=multi.value
    yr_vals=[int(y) for y in yr]
    new_data=df[df.year.isin(yr_vals)]
    source.data=new_data
    push_notebook(handle=t)

multi.on_change('value',update)
t=show(row(multi,data_table),notebook_handle=True)
```

Comment: I am afraid you can only use JavaScript callbacks (CustomJS) on Jupyter notebooks. If you want to use python callbacks then you will need to run bokeh as a server application (with `bokeh serve`)

Comment: I think updating bokeh plots from the notebook works fine (see [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#notebook-handles)) but the bokeh widgets (multiselect) do not work. Apparently you can use the jupyter widgets to interact ([next point in the same documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyter-interactors))

Comment: @ChesuCR It is definitely possible to embed full bokeh server apps with real python callbacks in notebooks, for some time now. See: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`push_notebook` is uni-directional. That is, you can only push changes from the IPython kernel, *to* the JavaScript front end. No changes from the UI are propagated back to the running Python kernel. In other words, `on_change` is not useful (without more work, see below) If you want that kind of interaction, there are a few options:

- Use `ipywidgets` with `push_notebook`. Typically this involved the `interact` function to automatically generate a simple UI with callbacks that use `push_notebook` to update the plots, etc. based on the widget values. Just to be clear, this approach uses `ipywidgets`, which are *not* Bokeh built-in widgets. You can see a full example notebook here:

  https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/notebook_comms/Jupyter%20Interactors.ipynb
- Embed a Bokeh server application. The Bokeh server is what makes it possible for `on_change` callbacks on Bokeh widgets to function. Typically this involves making a function that defines the app (by specifying how a new document is created):

  ```
  def modify_doc(doc):
      df = sea_surface_temperature.copy()
      source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

      plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', y_range=(0, 25))
      plot.line('time', 'temperature', source=source)

      def callback(attr, old, new):
          if new == 0:
              data = df
          else:
              data = df.rolling('{0}D'.format(new)).mean()
          source.data = ColumnDataSource(data=data).data

      slider = Slider(start=0, end=30, value=0, step=1, title="Smoothing by N Days")
      slider.on_change('value', callback)

      doc.add_root(column(slider, plot))
  ```

  Then calling `show` on that function:

  ```
  show(modify_doc)
  ```

  A full example notebook is here:

  https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb
- (Hacky option) some people have combined `CustomJS` callbacks with Jupyers JS function `kernel.execute` to propagate values back to the kernel.