# Interactive Bokeh plot in Jupyter Notebook not updating

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I have written the following little script with which I simply want to plot an interactive sine curve where I can change the amplitude of the curve and the title of the figure. Though, as output I get the figure together with the slider and text field but altering the values does not change the curve or title.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from ipywidgets import interact


x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,2000)
y = np.sin(x)

df_data = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y})

p = figure(plot_height=300,plot_width=600,title="my sine wave")
p.line('x','y',source=df_data)


# Set up widges
amplitude = Slider(title="amlitude", value=0.0, start=0.01, end=0.99, step=0.01)
text = TextInput(title="title", value='my sine wave')

# Update
def update_data(attrname, old, new):

    # Get the current slider values
    a = amplitude.value
    b = text.value
    
    y = amplitude*np.sin(x)
    

    output_notebook()
    show(row(p,widgetbox([amplitude,text])))
    
    


text.on_change('value', update_data)
amplitude.on_change('value',update_data)
    


# Set to output the plot in the notebook

output_notebook()
show(row(p,widgetbox([amplitude,text])))
```

[image]

So as you can see, everything works fine instead of the updating of the plot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link a multiselect widget to a datatable using bokeh in a jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826750/how-to-link-a-multiselect-widget-to-a-datatable-using-bokeh-in-a-jupyter-noteboo)

Comment: `on_change` is only useful for a Bokeh server application (which can be embedded in a notebook, but has to be structured differently). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826750/how-to-link-a-multiselect-widget-to-a-datatable-using-bokeh-in-a-jupyter-noteboo/50850057#50850057

Answer (score 0):

> > everything works fine instead of the updating of the plot.

Within `update_data` you have to `show()` again as in your bottom lines or it won't refresh.

Comment: with output_notebook() ?

Comment: Yes both lines. If I omit the output_notebook() statement, the plot is opened in the browser but it still doesn not change anyting